# Why am I getting "Your Application is crashing Error" on Meteor.js tutorial?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just started learning Meteor.js and am following the To-Do App tutorial, which you can view below.

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events (this is also the step the error occurred on)

So I was following the directions on the above step and I believe i might of had a type on the Javascript code to listen to the submit event.

I added the submit code (with the type) and went to my web app locally and added some text in the input and pressed enter..then I got this error.

```
/Users/kassdhs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
    at simple-todos.js:11:1
    at /Users/kassdhs/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/simple-todos.js:32:4
    at /Users/kassdhs/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/kassdhs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/kassdhs/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

TERMINAL ERROR

```
    => Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

This happened before when I tried doing the tutorial so I had to reinstall Meteor and re-run the local server to start working on it. Do I have to do this every time I make a type and an error happens?

I hope not because I really like Meteor and feel like I can really learn it fast and strong.

If someone can help me fix this problem that would be amazing (also so I can continue the tutorial!)

Thank you

Comment: `Template` may not be accessible on the`Server`. Try moving template code into the `Client` folder.

Answer (score 1):

On the previous step in the tutorial your code `simple-todos.js` looked like this (extra comments added):

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });

// Add Template.body.event handlers here

}  // Closing brace for the Meteor.isClient block
```

Ensure when you add the submit handler it is within the `Meteor.isClient` block so that it is only executed on the server.
Template is not defined on the server, causing the ReferenceError.

When you get server side errors, the server will recover when you fix the code.  However you may have to manually refresh your web browser before hot code push starts again.